# Swift - Large title transition with tableView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, transition

I'm trying to code the "Sign up" part of my app.
I'm using Large Title for that. If I use normal ViewControllers, everything is good, but if I use TableViewController, I have a really bad transition when I change the ViewController:

[image]

I can see a black background. Do you have any idea about how I could correct this?

EDIT: If I set isTranslucent = true, it's okay, but I would like to have a white NavigationBar. Do you know how to do that?

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
         // tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
      }
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}

@IBAction func continueAction(_ sender: Any) {
      let signupSecondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignupSecondViewController") as! SignupSecondViewController
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signupSecondVC, animated: true)
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "backgroundNav")
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default)
```

The NavigationBar is still translucent, even if the imageBackground is opaque ...

[image]

Comment: Does it help if you change `isTranslucent = false` to `true`?

Comment: @matt yes ... If I change isTranslucent = true for the SecondViewController, it's working. Do you know how I could have a non-translucent title and still have a great animation?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Large titles are tricky and you have to implement them Apple's way. If you find this restriction onerous, please file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: To govern the color of a navigation bar while letting it be translucent, use the `backgroundImage`.

Comment: @matt How am I supposed to use the backgroundImage?

Answer (score 4):

Set the `isTranslucent` of your navigation bar to `true` and govern its color by way of its [`backgroundImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624968-setbackgroundimage).

Comment: How can I do this? Add a white backgroundImage? I don't want a translucent navigationBar

Comment: It won't be translucent if the background image is opaque.